# Codificación en posgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datatables, caracteres, codificación

Necesito cargar un archivo.txt a posgreSQL el cual que contiene caracteres especiales como Ñ, tildes, etc. Al momento de cargarlo desde la consola me indica un error de codificación ya que no está respetando la letra Ñ.
Revisé la codificación y está en UTF-8, intenté recodificarlo de ASCII a UTF-8 no funcionó, también intenté abrirlo desde el bloc de notas para guardarlo como UTF-8, cabe mencionar que para este caso dividí el archivo en varias partes guardé cada parte con la codificación y posterior a esto lo concatené puesto que pesa 6 Gb y el bloc de notas es imposible leerlo. Sin embargo, tampoco funcionó.
¿Hay alguna otra manera de poder cargar el archivo?

Comment: falta mas informacion, por ejemplo el collation y el encoding que tienes actualmente en tu base de datos y en la tabla ... que comando estas ejecutando o lo estas haciando desde algun lenguaje de programacion ...

Comment: Agrega informacion de en que codificacion esta tu base y como estas cargando el archivo

Answer (score -1):

Revisando el caso, pueda ser que la BD que estas intentando cargar el archivo no tenga la codificación UTF-8, puedes confirmar esto con el siguiente comando:

```
SHOW client_encoding;
```

En caso de que tu BD no tenga la codificación, puedes establecerla solo para tu sesión con el siguiente comando.

```
SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8';
```

Después ya puedes intentar de nuevo cargar el archivo.

Espero te haya sido de utilidad!

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).